# How to define PagerTitleStrip two sides TextView Width?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented `ViewPager` with `PagerTitleStrip`. `PagerTitleStrip` can show three textview such as previous fragment text, current fragment text and next fragment text. I observed that previous and next textview size depends on current textview size. My `ViewPager` looks like this:

[image]

In `ViewPager` the two sides text area width stretched (based on middle text area) but I want to make the two side text area width fixed. Such as 40dp width. Is it is  possible to fix the width of previous and next textview. How can I achieve this. Any kinds of solution???

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to override PagerTitleStrip?
You can take a look at Android Source Code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.java), it has quite a lot of calculations, but looks quite simple =], actually you probably will find the answer on it's super class.

Comment: Can you share me some code snippet? Actually I want to know how to set the width of previous and next textview.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the solution at all, but start looking to this lines: {mPrevText.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        mCurrText.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        mNextText.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);}
It is on 441-444 of PagerTitleStrip.